# Can I use /etc/nginx/conf.d to add locations?

Tags: nginx, ansible

I have some nginx config snippets, which add locations, i.e. to send requests to a certain path to a fastcgi server.
For a clean deployment with ansible, I would like to use the `/etc/nginx/conf.d` folder to add them there.

The problem is, `location /something` belongs into a server block and the default server is already defined in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`. And when I want to deploy more different locations, they should not need an own vhost for each include.

Possibly even a site in `sites-enabled` would be useful, but it should still be composable. Different snippets can be included in the same config without knowing if other snippets are installed or not.

Is there a clean way to include location blocks from config snippets without modifying the default config?

Answer (score 5):

The include statement in nginx works also for partial config, not just full servers. So you could create a directory e.g. /etc/nginx/default-site-locations/ and put there all your location_1.conf ... location_n.conf files.

Then, in your default configuration, include all conf files from that directory with `include /etc/nginx/default-site-locations/*.conf`

Comment: My problem is, that I want to keep all configured site configs untouched, as I do not know what is configured and why. For adding things to the default config, I need to replace it or have a rather complicated script to insert the location block at the right place, without knowing if there are other modifications, e.g. from other ansible roles.

Comment: Since you want to add locations to the default config, you must at least insert a reference into the default config where nginx should look for additional locations. Modifying the default config without touching it is contradictory. The suggestion above adds only ONE line to the default config. But that one line is necessary to activate the behavior you want: Loading locations from a directory that you can modify with ansible without touching the default config again and again.

Comment: This would be the last resort option: replace the default config by a config with wildcard include for locations and then deploy the locations in small files. But this assumes that nobody has modified the default config. I fear this is my only option, beside deploying a config with another server in it (which cannot be ``default_server`` then) and access the deployed locations under name given in the server-config.